# Two FOREIGN key constraints from single parent table not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create two tables with two foreign key constrains from single parent table.

What is wrong in these two parent-child tables here?

I have only these two tables in database (I dropped all other tables):

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `db_test`.`tbl_test_monitoring_type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_test`.`tbl_test_monitoring_type` (
  `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Synthetic ID for an Order Status.',
  `monitoring_type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `message_type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `creared_by` VARCHAR(10) NULL COMMENT 'staff PK number',
  `modified_by` VARCHAR(10) NULL COMMENT 'staff PK number',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ukidx_monitoring_type` (`monitoring_type` ASC, `message_type` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'Lookup table for storing monitorying types.';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `db_test`.`tbl_test_monitoring`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_test`.`tbl_test_monitoring` (
  `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Synthetic ID for an Order Status.',
  `monitoring_type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `message_type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date of monitoring recorded.',
  `message` VARCHAR(500) NULL COMMENT 'More information attached by the user.' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ukidx_monitoring_type_message_type` (`monitoring_type` ASC, `message_type` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_test_message_type_monitoring`
    FOREIGN KEY (`message_type`)
    REFERENCES `db_test`.`tbl_test_monitoring_type` (`message_type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'Table to store complete information about monitoring';
```

I am getting issue in the second foreign key constaraint. ie. if I add second foreign then the table tbl_test_monitoring not created. The second constraint

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_test_message_type_monitoring`
    FOREIGN KEY (`message_type`)
    REFERENCES `db_test`.`tbl_test_monitoring_type` (`message_type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

These two are two data bases which are depend on the any existing databases.
I tried by deleting all other tables even I am getting above error.

Comment: You need an unique index on message_type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my query:

```
CREATE TABLE parent(
`ID` int(11) default NULL,
`name` varchar(100) default NULL,
`city` varchar(100) default NULL,
key (name,city),
primary key (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table child(
userID int not null,
`name` varchar(100) default NULL,
`city` varchar(100) default NULL,
key (name,city),
FOREIGN KEY (name,city) REFERENCES parent(name,city),
primary key (userID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

The referenced column needs to be indexed. Try like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_test_monitoring_type` (
  `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Synthetic ID for an Order Status.',
  `monitoring_type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `message_type` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `creared_by` VARCHAR(10) NULL COMMENT 'staff PK number',
  `modified_by` VARCHAR(10) NULL COMMENT 'staff PK number',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX idx_messagetype (message_type),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ukidx_monitoring_type` (`monitoring_type` ASC, `message_type` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = 'Lookup table for storing monitorying types.';
```

Comment: tried but no luck-  getting "Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'db_test.tbl_test_monitoring' (errno: 150)
"

Comment: You talk about 2 foreign key constraints in the title, but there's only one. Are you missing information in your question. When I try with the adjusted create statements on http://sqlfiddle.com it works absolutely fine.